# How to use the tel: function (html) and secure with https

Tags: html, https, href, tel

i've a qeustion about securing my website with https and using the:
    href="tel:056565546" attribute in html.

I was trying to make a website with a call function so that people did't have to remember the mobile number but just press a call me function.
This work just fine with hreff and some css.

The problem is when is try to secure it with https(i am using netlify they got a free option to setup https) i get a error before in the console saying: "that data can leak because of the form and because i hard coded the mobile number"
I tryed to put the number in with javascript but it still does't solve the problem with https but now i don't get anny errors thats why i can't show you this error. :(

i tryed searching on the internet for a good solution but without anny succes.

Can anny one send my in de right direct. i would like to have this tel:009099 function of HTML and also the https.

thanks in advance

I hope you guy's get what i writing. English is not my first language :)

here the code

```
 <section id="bel-chanel">
     <form class="contact-form">
         <button class="contact-button" type="submit" name="submit"> 
         <p class`enter code here`="contact-submit">
         <a href="tel:+31612779366">call me</a><p></button>
     </form>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to write a JS `onclick` (or something similar) to handle this `tel`:

```
window.top.location = 'tel:....';
```